# Android - Activity Home/Up arrow has additional padding/margin with SDK 24

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-sdk-tools, android-actionbar-compat

I've just updated my app from using SDK 23 to SDK 24.

A problem has arisen for my activities that have show the Up/Home arrow (i.e., `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`) in that there is now additional (unwanted) space between the Up arrow and the activity title.

For activities that don't have an Up arrow, the activity title is in exactly the same place as before, which suggests the additional padding/margin is associated with the Up arrow rather than with the activity title.

My question is how do I change the layout so that it looks the same with SDK 24 as it did with SDK 23?

**Small gap between Up arrow and title using SDK 23:**
[image: Small gap between Up arrow and title using SDK 23]

**Large (unwanted) gap between Up arrow and title using SDK 24:**
[image: Large (unwanted) gap between Up arrow and title using SDK 24]

Here is my old build.gradle (SDK 23):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 42
        versionName "0.42"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.0.2'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
}
```

Here is the new build.gradle (SDK 24):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 42
        versionName "0.42"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.0.2'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
}
```

Comment: By the way you can use buildToolsVersion "24"

Comment: If I try that, it says "failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.0"... but it also gives you a link to install it. :-) (Incidentally, it hasn't fixed the problem.)

Comment: Have you downloaded Android SDK Build-tools from SDK manager ?

Comment: According to Android SDK, everything was up-to-date but I've installed Build Tools rev 24.0.0. The problem is still there, though.

Comment: I saw this as well. It seems that if you downgrade all the support libraries from 24.0.0 to 23.4.0 it is back to normal. So it seems to be a support library issue?

Comment: Please read my answer. It should work well.

Comment: I'm glad that it worked. So please accept my answer if you don't mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think that this padding is a new standard to match Material spec in SDK 24.
First you must hide default toolbar title by this code:

> getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

Then make a file called `toolbar.xml` and add these codes in that file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" <!-- Add margin -->
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:text="Toolbar Title" <!-- Your title text -->
        android:textColor="@color/white" <!-- Matches default title styles -->
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

As you see, you can control everything in this file. Look at this line in toolbar.xml :

> app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"

This is what you want. Goodluck.

Comment: OK, so the main requirement here is to replace the ActionBar with a Toolbar. I didn't need your TextView, so this was my toolbar.xml: `
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>`

Comment: I added the toolbar to my activities by adding `<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>`  to each activity layout file.

Comment: And then the easiest way to update the code of all my activities was to add this method to my BaseActivity file (which all my activities extend):

Comment: `@Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResId) {
        super.setContentView(layoutResId);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            toolbar.setTitle(getTitle());
            //toolbar.setSubtitle("Subtitle");
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

    }`

Comment: I'm glad that it worked. So please accept my answer if you don't mind. Thank you.

Comment: What would you do in case you want to have the same behavior of setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false) , on a Toolbar view that isn't the action bar ?

Comment: Is there a way to apply this to an ActionBar, and not replace the ActionBar with a Toolbar?

Answer (score 30):

This was answered in the Android Issues Tracker. The link is:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213826

Add `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"` to the toolbar view.

Comment: That's exactly what I did

Answer (score 3):

try this code to remove unwanted space 
use it according to your use :-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with XML only, without needing to add a custom Toolbar (but using the default one).

**styles.xml**

```xml
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
         if you want to further customize the home/up icon,
         uncomment the following and specify a drawable
    -->
    <!--<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item>-->
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/ActionBar.NoPad</item>
</style>

<!-- Remove padding with home/up arrow -->
<style name="ActionBar.NoPad" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="contentInsetStartWithNavigation">0dp</item>"
</style>
```