# Android SDK version 24 added extra padding between Back button and other toolbar elements

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-7.0-nougat

With Android SDK 23 padding between avatar and back button is OK.

[image]

But after increasing SDK to 24 padding increased. I am not sure is this new default padding, or I just need to adjust my code for new SDK.

[image]

Same issue is valid for other toolbar elements.

[image]

my toolbar layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/Toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/color_primary"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            >

            <include layout="@layout/partial_toolbar"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

partial_toolbar.xml

```
       <merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_content_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_app_logo"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_white_24dp"
            android:tint="@color/toolbar_foreground"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

        <com.example.ui.extensions.GroupAvatarView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_group_logo"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/right_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:textColor="@color/toolbar_foreground"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

</merge>
```

Comment: This was already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859807/android-activity-home-up-arrow-has-additional-padding-margin-with-sdk-24

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your java code

```
toolbar.setContentInsetStartWithNavigation(0);
```